# Fetching all products of a store using phpclassic/php-shopify SDK

Tags: php, shopify

I wrote this snippet in order to fetch all the products of a store,

using [PHP Shopify SDK](https://github.com/phpclassic/php-shopify) :

```
$productCount = $shopify->Product->count();
$limit = 250;
$totalpage = ceil($productCount/$limit);

for($i=1; $i<=$totalpage; $i++){

  $params = array(
    'limit' => '250',
    'page' => $i
  ); 

  $products = $shopify->Product->get($params);
}
```

But I am getting only the first 50 products.
Do you have any suggestions on how to get them all?

Thanks in advance!

Answer (score 0):

You have to pass page_info instead Of page in params and you will get page info from responses like :

```
$page_info="";
for($i=1; $i<=$totalpage; $i++){
    $productResource = $shopify->Product();
    $params = array(
                'limit' => '250',
                'page_info' => $page_info
              );
              
    $product = $productResource->get($params);
    $nextPageProducts = $productResource->getNextPageParams();
    $page_info = $nextPageProducts['page_info'];
}
```

for the first page, you have to pass in empty page_info.

Answer (score 0):

I have created a function for our project that can fetch all resource items of a store. See example:

```
$this->existingProducts = $this->getAllResourceItems($this->shopify->Product());


private function getAllResourceItems(PHPShopify\ShopifyResource $resource): array
{
    $result = [];

    $page_info = '';
    while ($page_info !== NULL) {
        $params = [
            'limit' => '250', // max 250
            'page_info' => $page_info
        ];

        $items  = $resource->get($params);
        $result = array_merge($result, $items);

        $nextPageParams = $resource->getNextPageParams();
        $page_info      = $nextPageParams['page_info'];
    }

    return $result;
}
```